# Kafka not receiving messages when indicating group_id in Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, consumer, kafka-python

I am using Kafka (`kafka-python`) version 3.0.0-1.3.0.0.p0.40. I need to configure the consumer for the topic 'simulation' in Python. When I don't indicate the group_id, i.e. group_id = None it receives messages fine. However if I indicate the group_id, it doesn't receive any messages.

Here's my code in Python:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092',
                         group_id = 'myTestGroupID', enable_auto_commit = True)
consumer.subscribe(['simulation'])
# not using assign method here as auto_commit is enabled
# partitions = [TopicPartition('simulation',num) for num in range(0,9)]
# consumer.assign([TopicPartition('simulation', partitions[0])])

while not self.stop_event.is_set():
    for message in consumer:
        print(message)
```

I tried to search for some default values of group_id in consumer properties files, I've found one cloudera_mirrormaker however nothing changed.
I will need to use multiple consumers therefore it's important that I have a group_id and they share the same group_id.
In many sources I've found that the group_id can be any string...

When I run the consumer for this topic in the console it works and receives messages

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092 --topic simulation --from-beginning --consumer-property group.id=myTestGroupID  --partition 0
```

when I'm running kafka-consumer-groups.sh to list all available groups it's empty.

If anyone has an idea why it's stuck in Python, it would be so much appreciated.
Thanks a lot

Here is code for producer (I've reduced it for simplicity as in this case it doesn't change the problem)

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
class Producer(threading.Thread):
    ...
    def run(self):
        producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092')
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
            string = 'test %s' %time.time()
            producer.send('simulation', string.encode())
            time.sleep(0.5)
        producer.close()
```

Comment: can you describe that group on kafka `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group`

Comment: If you consumed all the offsets in the console for the same group, then python wouldn't get any messages, otherwise, what is `self.stop_event.is_set()`? Please show a [MCVE]

Comment: @Deadpool it always gives me this Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to The consumer group command timed out while waiting for group to initialize

Comment: @stovfl I've edited my question by adding the producer part. I've simplified it as it doesn't change the problem. I've just checked, I have kafka-python version 1.4.3 it definitely should support this

Comment: The **Error** from `groups.sh --describe` should not happend. Retry with a different **topic** and **group_id**. Also simplify your consumer testcase to use it without the `while not...` part.

Comment: Any luck on this? I've got the same issue.

Comment: @noname yeah I've finally solved it. That was my issue:  [omkafka config file](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/omkafka.html) partitions.number attr was 1 by default, we changed it to 100 as was needed and it started working! I hope it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally solved it.

That was my issue: `omkafka` config file `partitions.number` attr was `1` by default.

We changed it to `100` as was needed and it started working! I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Kafka not receiving messages when indicating group_id

---

> Try, pass the 'topic' on `KafkaConsumer` instantiating, like in the [Documentation](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html?highlight=dynamic%20partition%20assignment):
>
> ```
> # join a consumer group for dynamic partition assignment and offset commits
> from kafka import KafkaConsumer
> consumer = KafkaConsumer('simulation', group_id='myTestGroupID')
> for msg in consumer:
>     print (msg)
> ```
>
> The [Documentation: KafkaConsumer](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html) is clear about the type of `group-id`:
>
> **group_id** (str or None) – The name of the consumer group to join for dynamic partition assignment (if enabled), and to use for fetching and committing offsets. If None, auto-partition assignment (via group coordinator) and offset commits are disabled. Default: None

Comment: I've tried this too indicating the topic in when instantiating but it didn't help... from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('simulation', group_id='myTestGroupID',bootstrap_servers='XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092',
                            enable_auto_commit = True)
for msg in consumer:
    print (msg)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, partially not receiving messages (most of the messages are lost) when dealing with a high latency environment and large messages (>1Mb).

I did not put a lot of effort on finding the root cause but my guess is that consumer re-balancing is initiated before the message processing is done, which seems to cause issues when no other consumer is available (in my case i had a single consumer or two consumers that suffered the same issue).

What did the trick for me was increasing **max_poll_interval_ms**
and setting **max_poll_records=1**

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092',
                     group_id = 'myTestGroupID', 
                     enable_auto_commit = True,
                     max_poll_interval_ms=5000,
                     max_poll_records=1)
```

you can find more info at:
https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html
at the **Detecting Consumer Failures** section.